# Google Docs - Autopopulate live form

Tags: javascript, google-docs, google-docs-api

i have a webpage that host events (example: http://www.mysite.com/test/events/5493.html) that page holds information such as event title and other info, using google docs i've created a form that fills out my spreadsheet (survey)

The issue is that how can i get the event information from "5493.html" and autopopulate the fields that i set up on the google docs form (live form)

Event Name: [auto populate from the "5493" page]

Date of Event:  [auto populate from the "5493" page]

Please rate:

question:

question

[submit button]

What i want to do is to send the link (live form link) and when someone else wants to fill out the googel survey form, those 2 fields are auto-populated to avoid typo mistakes.

i know there is a way to manually modify the link however are there any automated options???

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like google docs now supports it.
See: https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=160000